# Multiple Users in Android 4.0.4

Tags: multi-user

I have a Toshiba Thrive AT105 running on Android 4.0.4.

I wish to use the multiple users function on it to share it with other users.

Can this be done on Android 4.0.4? If not, how can I upgrade to another android version which can support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

There might be several approaches you *could* try. No guarantees whatsoever, and I didn't try any of those. Still mentioning them, so you can investigate for yourself. Note further that these solutions will require root access on your device.

First, there's an app called [SwitchMe](http://www.appbrain.com/app/fahrbot.apps.switchme), which already was available before the multi-user feature was released with Android 4.2. *SwitchMe* works with Android 2.1 and higher.

Second, our friends at XDA have a thread on [Porting Multi Users JB to ICS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1845008) (but it seems that approach died before producing a workable solution).